# CSRF problems with sailsjs

Tags: node.js, sails.js, csrf

I am having some trouble with the csrf of sails.js, I activated it and create the hidden field like in the sailsjs documentation, but when I submit the form I always get this response:

```
Error: Forbidden
    at Object.exports.error (/Users/matheus/Development/javascript/activity_overlord/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:62:13)
    at createToken (/Users/matheus/Development/javascript/activity_overlord/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:82:55)
    at /Users/matheus/Development/javascript/activity_overlord/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:48:24
    at routes.before./* (/Users/matheus/Development/javascript/activity_overlord/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/csrf/index.js:26:28)
    at _bind.enhancedFn (/Users/matheus/Development/javascript/activity_overlord/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:375:4)
    at callbacks (/Users/matheus/Development/javascript/activity_overlord/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
    at param (/Users/matheus/Development/javascript/activity_overlord/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
    at pass (/Users/matheus/Development/javascript/activity_overlord/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
    at nextRoute (/Users/matheus/Development/javascript/activity_overlord/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:100:7)
    at callbacks (/Users/matheus/Development/javascript/activity_overlord/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:167:11)
```

Somebody can help me to find a solution? I think it is a simple thing to do, I just don't know what is this "simple thing"

Comment: Look at the HTML source of your form in the browser.  Does the hidden field you created actually have the CSRF value in it?

Comment: I'm having a problem with this on and off which is very annoying

Answer (score 2):

If your app is in production mode, it will mask the csrf mismatch response with "Forbidden" as per the default forbidden.js file.

You can override this by creating the file "api/responses/forbidden.js" and copying the contents of this into it

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/responses/defaults/forbidden.js#L35

Notice that I highlighted the line causing this, this is where you will add a check for data === 'CSRF Mismatch' and avoid changing the data to undefined, or change the response however you want it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to get CSRF token by calling the webservice (/csrfToken). In response, you'll get a token. You need to send that token in all subsequent requests to server.

```
$http.get($scope.baseUrl + '/csrfToken')
    .success(function(csrfObj) {
        csrfToken = csrfObj._csrf;
    });

$http.post('/chat/addconv/',{user:$scope.chatUser,message: $scope.chatMessage, _csrf:csrfToken});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple directive for this

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
      .module('app')
      .directive('csrf', csrf);

  csrf.$inject = ['$http'];

  function csrf($http) {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        $http({method: 'GET', url: '/csrfToken', cache: true}).then(function(result) {
          try {
            $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-Token'] = result.data._csrf;
          } catch(e) {
            // do something
          }
        });
      }
    };

    return directive;
  }
})();
```

Then use it with the form

```
<form csrf name="form">
```